# Angularjs: linking to phone's mapping app

Tags: ios, angularjs, android-intent

I have a webapp that wants to offload walking / driving directions to a phone's native apps. This would be Google Maps app and maps.apple.com for Android and iOS respectively.  I can detect the phone from the user agent presumably, but I can't work out how to configure the link.

```
<li><a href ng-click="geoHandler()"> Directions</a></li>
```

This is what I have in the relevant controller.

```
$scope.geoHandler = function() {
    // user agent sniffing here
    var path = "geo:0,0?q="+$scope.resto.lat+","+$scope.resto.lng+"("+$scope.resto.rname+")";
    // var path = http://maps.apple.com/?ll=$scope.resto.lat+","+$scope.resto.lng
    return $location.path(path);
}
```

When I had the geo link as the href in the html, the phone did the right thing, but now this code is taking me simply to the home page of my SPA.

So, my questions are:

- is ng-click the right way to go (I can't use a function with ng-href I think);
- how do I launch an intent via $location?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I moved to a different and simpler approach. Not sure whether it is the most elegant, but it works.

View

```
<a ng-href="{{geoPath}}">Directions</a>
```

Controller

```
if ( /iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent))
    path = "http://maps.apple.com/?ll="+$scope.resto.lat+","+$scope.resto.lng";
else path = "geo:0,0?q="+$scope.resto.lat+","+$scope.resto.lng+"("+$scope.resto.rname+")";
$scope.geoPath = path;
```